# Windows 10 Home Account Separation

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm using Win 10 Home version and very often I'm experiencing very strange behavior: some system settings are used from another account when I switch account.

For example: I have two accounts with different keyboard layouts. When I switch from one account to another the layout setting remain. So I'm logged in and I'm using keyboard layout from another account.

Also once I logged in and music (or some video) start playing and it was something what was started with another account. This almost looks like security vulnerability.

Do you have any idea how this can happen and how to avoid this?

Just to make it complete: I'm using Win 10 Home, version 1909, build 18363.1016.

Comment: I think you are dealing with more than one issue at the same time.  Have you seen [this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/unable-to-change-keyboard-layout-for-second-user/fae7258e-9ddf-441f-b340-d00645d6d060?page=2) ? .. that might explain the keyboard issue.  What player are you using that is reproducing the info from the other login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some fixes you can try:

- Create a new user profile, and import files and re-configure the settings as you wish.
- Run `sfc /scannow` and `dism /online /cleanup-image /restore-Health` in elevated command prompt.
- Try to insert the windows 10 installation media and reset your PC or perform System restore.

Comment: `scf` scan didn't find anything and `dism` for some reason ended with error.
But I tried to recreate the user profile - delete the old one and create new. And it looks ok. I didn't experienced this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any idea how this can happen

Seems to be a bug

> and how to avoid this?

Being a bug you can't do much to avoid it. You might try reinstalling Windows. If that doesn't help and the issue is indeed serious, then you need to try another OS.